# Makefile has "@" symbol all through, is this correct or should it be something else?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile for something I downloaded, it is full of @ symbols like so:

```
@SET_MAKE@

srcdir = @srcdir@
top_srcdir = @top_srcdir@
VPATH = @srcdir@
```

It stops at @SET_MAKE@ saying missing separator.  Should these @ be quotes or something?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a makefile?

Comment: Those `@...@` sequences look like tokens that will be replaced by some other tool to *create* a `makefile`.

Comment: I think you're looking at a `Makefile.in` file, not a `Makefile`.  You are supposed to run the `configure` script to generate a `Makefile`.  Please see the `INSTALL` or `README` or similar file that should be provided describing what you need to do.